# phonegap javascript variable is empty in callback function

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I'm currently building an app with phonegap using the webkit SQLite in phonegap. Doing this i got a problem inserting variables into an SQLite Table:

```
function addTrack(track){

    var trackItem = track;
    alert(trackItem.name);
    db.transaction(addingTrack, errorCB);

    function addingTrack(tx) {

        alert (trackItem.name);
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Tracks (name) VALUES ("' + trackItem.name + "')');
}

}
```

While the first alert returns the name of the track, as i would expect, the second returns an empty string.
Note that the attribute trackItem.name in the second alert seems to be defined, but only contains an empty string, instead of not being defined at all.

The trackItem is not used anywhere else in the script.
Also, declaring trackItem globally at the beginning of the script does not change anything. Does anyone have an idea why the variable is not being passed into the callback function?

Comment: Could something else be changing the name, since the `track` variable is passed in to the `addTrack` function? Whatever called `addTrack` could be changing `track.name` after calling `addTrack`.

Comment: That was it! in the other script i reset the track. Didn't think this would effect the track object in this script. Thanks for the help!